# Fixed width of columns in html table

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use a table where I will define fixed width columns. Each column width is pre-defined and applied to a 'th' element in the table header via:
ng-style='{"width":get_width[i]+"px"}', where the get_width function returns a number.

This works just fine as long as the text does not exceed the column width specified. If it does, the width changes to accommodate the entire text.

Question, how can I use CSS to force the column width to my specification? The text may be truncated if longer.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Hmm, fixed widths should constrain any text in them - http://jsfiddle.net/8QkmD/. Please demo the problem by posting code and, ideally, a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Utkanos, I tried this with frameworks such as Bootstrap and with just plain simple CSS, no luck. Will try to post some redacted code soon.

Answer (score 6):

You can truncate text using css: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dy5Mq/4/)

CSS

```
.div1 {
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:12em;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box.</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Checked this out. Found this works for textboxes, but not in tables. see code below

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

#div1
{
white-space:nowrap; 
width:12em; 
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis; 
border:1px solid #000000;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer to include a div inside the td.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Adding a div worked. Looks like width definitions only within a div. I have added the css settings I applied to the div as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, set the width of the table as a whole by styling the `<table>` element.  Evidently a lot of implementations of CSS expand the columns to fit text until they bump up against the maximum width of the table.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8892235/1378487)

Comment: I plan to dump a large amount of data to this table with many columns (in excess of 25), so planning to utilize the max width is not a feasible approach. I expect that the columns that are important will be displayed ahead with fixed widths that I will manually optimize as part of the initial setup. My user may further change column width at runtime.

Comment: Think of Excel columns, that is the behavior I am trying to mimic.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set table layout fixed and set overflow hidden for cells and you have to use

```
<table class="fixed-table">
    <col width="20px" />
    <col width="30px" />
    <col width="40px" />
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

.fixed-table{ table-layout:fixed; word-break: break-all;}
.fixed-tabletd { overflow: hidden; }
```