# Fluid table: Truncate cell contents when needed, otherwise keep the table as narrow as possible

Tags: html, css, overflow, html-table

I have an HTML 5 table with three rows and four columns (two attribute/value pairs per row) on a responsive page (Bootstrap).

In desktop view (or with little content), I would like the table *not* to fill the entire width available, just enough to show the data. Columns should have individual widths, just enough to show their content. In other words, I want white space to the right of the table, when possible.

In mobile view (or with lots of content), I would like the cell contents to truncate (e.g. using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`), not to wrap. If possible, I want the attribute columns to truncate first, to a pre-set minimum. It's OK without that prioritization if it can't be solved elegantly.

Desired outcome:

[image]

I have browsed Stack Overflow etc. for several hours, and most solutions I find (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239758/css-truncate-table-cells-but-fit-as-much-as-possible), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891779/in-html-table-how-do-you-force-cell-text-to-truncate-and-not-increase-the-width)) demands the width of the table to be set, often to 100%, which is undesirable for my purposes. I have seen people mentioning putting `div` elements inside `td` elements, but without examples, and I haven't been able to figure it out on my own.

I don't have to solve this using `table`, so other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bjornte/dvxr2xod/).

### Strategy:

Use a hidden table to glean the desired cell widths of the visible table.

### Tactic:

In addition to the table that the user shall see, a hidden "shadow" table, with identical content, must be created directly above the visible table.

The shadow table must allow the content to wrap inside the cells (this is default `table` behavior).

When the page has loaded and at every window resize, `show()` the shadow table, measure the `width` of every `td` in the top row, then `hide()` the shadow table. Then copy the `width` values to the corresponding `td` elements in the visible table, which must have [Chris Coyier's truncate](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) applied.

Works in all browsers I've tested, including mobile.

### Bonus tips:

- Use `&shy;` to wrap long words if necessary, and `&nbsp;` to stop words from wrapping. This can be applied only in the shadow table.
- Use `1px` more cell padding in the shadow table due to a bug in Internet Explorer - otherwise, IE's visible table sometimes becomes slightly wider than the shadow table.

### JavaScript (requiring jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadEvents() {
  initFluidTables();
}

// Resize fluid table(s)
function resizeFluidTables() {

  // Show source cells
  $( ".fluid-table-invisible-source" ).show(0);

  var fluidTableCellWidth = [];

  // Measure (normally invisible) source cells
  $( ".fluid-table-invisible-source td" ).each(function( index, value ) {
    fluidTableCellWidth[index] = $( this ).width();
  });

  // Resize (always visible) target cells. Adding 1 pixel due to apparent bug in Firefox.
  $( ".fluid-table-visible-target td>i" ).each(function( index, value ) {
    $( this ).css({'width': fluidTableCellWidth[index]+1 });
  });

  // Re-hide source cells
  $( ".fluid-table-invisible-source" ).hide();

}

// Create table(s) to be fluid
function initFluidTables() {

  // Create a container. Not really necessary, but keeps DOM tidier.
  $(".fluid-table").wrap( "<div></div>" );

  // This looks like a mess. What it does, is that .fluid-table duplicates itself, and each sibling gets a different class.
  $(".fluid-table").each(function() {
    $( this ).clone().appendTo( $( this ).addClass( "fluid-table-invisible-source" ).parent() ).addClass( "fluid-table-visible-target" );
  });

  // Add truncating element inside target cells
  $(".fluid-table-visible-target td").wrapInner( "<i></i>");

  // Truncate table contents at first drawing of the DOM and every time the window resizes
  resizeFluidTables();
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    resizeFluidTables();
  });
}
</script>
```

### CSS:

```
.fluid-table td { padding-right: 5px; }

.fluid-table td:nth-child(odd) { color: #aaa; }

.fluid-table-visible-target td>i {
  font-style: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* source slighly more padded than target due to IE bug */

.fluid-table-invisible-source td:nth-child(even) {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.fluid-table-visible-target td:nth-child(even) {
  padding-right: 9px;
}
```

### Sample table:

Note use of `&shy;` and `&nbsp;` to indicate where you (do not) want the text to truncate.

```
<table class="fluid-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Avail&shy;able <i>until</i>:</td><td>No&nbsp;expiry date</td><td>Avail&shy;ability:</td><td>Worldwide</td><td></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Year:</td><td>2016</td><td>Length:</td><td>29&nbsp;minutes</td><td></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>First broad&shy;cast:</td><td>Feb&nbsp;2</td><td>Last broad&shy;cast:</td><td>Feb&nbsp;3</td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `div` inside the `td` and use [Chris Coyier's truncate](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/). Also, set the `width` of the truncate container to `100%` to truncate based on the available space rather than a fixed width.

Comment: Hi Amin, thank you for your feedback. I tested this as well as a host of other solutions. Your suggestion, at least in my tests, does not work because the `table` won't shrink horizontally once there are `div` elements with `width:100%` inside it. Chris Coyier's truncate is useful though. I found another solution that includes his CCS and will submit it as an answer.